# What is the difference between $(u \cdot \nabla)v$ and $u\cdot(\nabla v)$ when written in Einstein notation?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, index-notation

What is the difference between $(u \cdot \nabla)v$ and $u\cdot(\nabla v)$ when written in Einstein notation? I understand that they are different, but I'm not quite sure how. I've proven that $u \cdot (\nabla u)=\frac{1}{2}\nabla (u\cdot u)-u \times (\nabla \times u)$. I want to prove stuff with $(u \cdot \nabla)v$ but I don't know how to write it in Einstein notation.

Both $u$ and $v$ are vector fields.

Comment: One is a vector, the other is a scalar. So for the vector expression (the first), you write the $i$th component.

Comment: v is a vector field in both equations. the answer to both equations for vector fields. Look at "vector dot product" on the following link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities#Product_rule_for_the_gradient

Comment: Does $\nabla v$ denote the divergence ? If yes, $u\cdot\nabla v$ is a scalar product and shouldn't be be written with a $\cdot$.

Comment: @SamC. I agree that $v$ can be a vector field in both equations. However, the result of $(u\cdot\nabla)v$ is a vector, whereas the result of $u\cdot(\nabla v)$ is a scalar. I'm not sure I agree with the wiki article. For one thing, interpreting $u\cdot(\nabla v)$ as a scalar is a perfectly natural thing - therefore the notation is ambiguous and ought to be sharpened. For another, the article to which the wiki linked did not show what the wiki article claimed. It had $\operatorname{grad}(u\cdot v)=(\operatorname{grad}u)^T v+(\operatorname{grad}v)^Tu$, which is not the same thing.

Comment: That is, I agree that $v$ *can be* a vector field in both equations; it certainly need not be.

Comment: @YvesDaoust no $\nabla v$ is not the divergence, it is the gradient of v.

Comment: @AdrianKeister Yes, after delving into textbooks, I realized that wikipedia page is, if not blatantly incorrect, a flagrant abuse of notation.

$u\cdot(\nabla u)=(u\cdot \nabla) u$ when $\nabla$ is consistently defined.

Comment: Related (I answered more or less this question here) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3217770/is-the-following-simplification-correct-in-vector-calculus/3217792?r=SearchResults&s=10%7C7.8283#3217792

Answer (score 1):

If both $u$ and $v$ are vector fields, then $u\cdot(\nabla v) = (u\cdot\nabla)v$, since
$$u\cdot(\nabla v) = u^{i}(\nabla_{i}v^{j}) = u^{i}\nabla_{i}v^{j}$$
$$(u\cdot\nabla)v = (u^{i}\nabla_{i})v^{j} = u^{i}\nabla_{i}v^{j} $$
i.e, there is no difference, both are different expressions for the same operation.

The formula you present is also valid with $(u\cdot\nabla)u$
$$u⋅(∇u) = (u\cdot\nabla)u = \frac{1}{2}∇(u⋅u)−u×(∇×u)$$
which, in index notation, is written as
$$u^{i}\nabla_{i}u_{j} = \frac{1}{2}\nabla_{j}(u^{i}u_{i}) - {\epsilon_{j}}^{kl}u_{k}{\epsilon_{l}}^{mn}\nabla_{m}u_{n}$$

Where did you get the idea that $u\cdot(\nabla v)$ is different from $(u\cdot\nabla)v$?

Comment: I think its reasonably common to write $\nabla v$ with $(\nabla v^i)^T$ as its rows. i.e. $\nabla v$'s $ij$th entry is $\nabla_j v^i$, and the contraction would then yield $u^i\nabla_j u^i = \frac12 \nabla_j |u|^2$. Instead $(u\cdot\nabla )v$ = $(\nabla v)u$.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to note that in the first, $v$ is a vector function while in the second, $v$ is a scalar function. Try writing out each bracket first:
$$\nabla v = \partial_i v\quad \text{so}\quad u \cdot (\nabla v) = u_i \partial_i v$$ while

$$u \cdot \nabla = u_i \partial_i \quad \text{so} \quad [(u \cdot \nabla) v]_j=u_i\partial_iv_j.$$

Comment: v is a vector field in both equations. the answer to both equations for vector fields. Look at "vector dot product" on the following link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities#Product_rule_for_the_gradient