# Is the following simplification correct in Vector calculus

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, fluid-dynamics

In vector calculus is $(A \cdot \nabla)A$ equivalent to $A \cdot \nabla A$?

In other words is finding the dot product of $A$ with the gradient of $A$ the same as the term in brackets?

It seems correct but I'm not certain

Comment: How do you define $\nabla A$ in terms of components?

Answer (score 0):

How do you define $$A\cdot\nabla A,$$ for it doesn't make sense if $A$ is a scalar field. If not, exactly then what do you mean by the gradient of a vector field?

Comment: scalar product is always commutative? not if one of the things involved is an operator (as in this case). specifically, $$A \cdot \nabla\ne\nabla \cdot A$$since LHS is an operator, and RHS is not.

Comment: @JohnDoe Oh, wow. That's true. Also, I had missed that $A\cdot\nabla A$ is nonsense.

Comment: Yes, the meaning of $\nabla A$ is ambiguous for a vector $A$. I suppose its a matrix, in which case the preceding dot product corresponds to multiplying by $A^T$. But I'd prefer to just leave it as $(A\cdot\nabla)A$, as the orientation of the matrix is ambiguous. It seems most natural to take $$[\nabla A]_{ij}=\frac{\partial A_j}{\partial x_i}$$ but I don't see any reason for this preference.

Comment: @JohnDoe As you say, even if we take it to be a matrix, which one out of $\nabla A$ or $\nabla A^T$? But I even meant that it's nonsense if $A$ is a scalar -- how does one define the *dot product* of a scalar and a vector, provided the vector has at least two components?

Comment: If $A$ is a scalar, then I'd interpret the dot product to just reduce to a regular multiplicative factor.

Comment: @JohnDoe Well, that's certainly not obvious at all, since dot products are defined on vectors, so that we must think of $A$ as a one dimensional vector; but then the product is not defined when $\nabla A$ has at least two components, which it always has indeed.

Comment: If you view it like that, then this formula is impossible for all possible tensor ranks that $A$ can be, since $\nabla A$ is guaranteed to have a rank which is higher by $1$, so no scalar product can be defined. I interpreted it as left multiplication in whichever way is obvious, in which case this formula still makes sense if $A$ is scalar or a vector. I think this is how it was intended by OP.

Answer (score 0):

Using Einstein summation notation, $$((A\cdot \nabla )A)_j = A_i\partial_i A_j$$ 
If like me, you write the Jacobian matrix $\nabla A$ as
$$ (\nabla A)_{ij} =\partial_jA_i = \begin{bmatrix}(\nabla A_1)^T \\ (\nabla A_2)^T \\\vdots\\  (\nabla A_N)^T \end{bmatrix}$$
Then if $A\cdot M$ is the contraction $(A\cdot M)_j := A_i M_{ij}$, then
$$(A\cdot \nabla A)_j = A_i(\nabla A)_{ij}=A_i\partial_jA_i ≠ ((A\cdot\nabla)A)_j $$
Instead we have
$$ (A\cdot \nabla) A=\nabla A\cdot A=(\nabla A)^TA$$
Compare with chain rule. Indeed, this term should pop out  when computing the $t$ derivative of $A(X(t))$, where $X'=A(X)$.

A last comment, if you were to compute $A\cdot \nabla f$ where $f$ is a scalar, then $A\cdot \nabla f = (A\cdot \nabla )f$.

Comment: Is there any reason why $(\nabla A)_{ij}$ is defined as $\partial_j A_i$ rather than $\partial _i A_j$?

Comment: @JohnDoe Its the way I learned it, you're free to choose the other convention. The nice thing about this one is that $A(x+h) - A(x) \approx \nabla A(x) h$

Comment: Ah ok. So if the other convention was used, OP's formula would hold. I guess the answer to this question depends on the convention OP uses.